# Xcode 8 - Simulate 3DTouch & ForceTouch

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, 3dtouch

Can someone tell me if we can simulate 3DTouch with the Xcode 8 iOS simulator and how?

The option in my simulator looks like disable.

[image: HARDWAREOPTION]

Comment: Please let me know which device you are using for developing iMac or Macbook pro with force touch ?

Comment: I think you are using the device without Force touch feature. If you have force touch feature, then by using "Use Trackpad Force" you can test the 3D touch and Force touch

Answer (score 0):

You need a Force Touch-enabled device, so either a Macbook with Force Touch-enabled trackpad, or any(?) Mac with a Magic Trackpad 2.

Did not tried it myself, but positive feedback here :

> I can confirm that with Xcode 7.3 beta 5 (7D162j), I see a menu item in the Simulator for "Use Trackpad Force for 3D Touch."  And when I connect my Magic Trackpad 2 to my '14 MacBook Air, that menu item becomes enabled and I can access peek & pop, shortcuts, and pretty much everything else.  It's not a perfect simulation of 3D Touch (after all, they're based on different user-interaction paradigms), and there's a bit of lag, but it should be more than sufficient to test on the simulator.

From: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26744